# STM32CUBEIDE st link gdb debug error in final launch sequence

Tags: ide, stm32, truestudio, stm32cubemx

So, I am learning stm32 mcus, using a nucleo f4 board.

Everything was working fine and now debug launch fails.

Actually, I was doing one debug, closed it and next debug session won't launch.

It starts debug on Linux or on Windows with OpenOCD, but ST-Link GDB debug fails (gdb does work on linux).

This is the error message:

[image: !https://imgur.com/a/cVve9rY]

Already did allow the stlink server in the windows firewall.

Comment: You need to detail further is you want someone to be able to help you. I assume you are using STM32CubeIDE, from your screen capture ? And the GDB server is not on the same machine as the IDE ? How did you configure the Debug Configuration ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using STM32CubeIDE. GDB server is on the same machine, and the configuration is default. Today I installed Atollic TrueSTUDIO and everything works with the same settings.

Comment: Do you mean you can debug properly with Atollic ? I know that once I had issues with STM32CubeIDE regarding the kind of Debug Configuration I was setting. It was working fine with OpenOCD but not at all with GDB.

Comment: Yes, Atollic works fine.

Comment: It is due to Avast antivirus. It deletes the exe file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avast antivirus was deleting the STLINK server exe file, added an exception and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Also the problem is the mass storage option (that allows use the explorer to grab directly the hex files) and makes conflicts with the ide. I solved the problem using explorer and ejecting the board, then debugger goes fine.